# import tag field from excel to TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am unable to import `tag` field from excel to TFS 2012. there are two ways currently to import into TFS from Excel:

1. If we export data from TFS to get a Template structure, `TAG` field would be read only. So user cannot make any changes to it.
2. If we use simple Excel where **field names in TFS** are given as **column names** and we try to migrate that data using *TestCase migrator Plus* tool (for Bug or TestCase work item in TFS), then it gives this **WARNING**: `Value of Field: Tags is modified from 'Sanity' to ''`

So eventually that TestCase or a Bug work item gets imported in TFS but **WITHOUT TAGS field**.

Kindly suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 does not support editing Tags in Excel.

This capability was introduced recently, in TFS 2013 Update 2.  See here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/05/vs-tfs-2013-2-update-2-ctp-released.aspx